# Get Bytes from an int to avoid bit shifting fun - Java (Median Filtering)

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing

I'm trying to perform a Median filter on an image in Java but it's terribly slow. Firstly, if any of you know of a standalone implementation I could use it would be fantastic if you could let me know. I'm implementing on Android, trying to replicate a small part of the JAI.

In my method I take each pixel, extract the R,G & B values using

```
r = pixel >> 16 & 0xFF
```

Or similar, find the median for the kernel and finish with

```
pixel = a | r <<16 | g << 8 | b
```

Is there any way I can grab the bytes from an int in such a way that this would be faster?

Kind regards,

Gavin

---

EDIT: Full code to help diagnose my low performance upon request

For the actual source file please go [here](http://code.google.com/p/miffed/source/browse/trunk/Miffed%20Demo/src/uk/ac/ic/doc/gea05/miffed/operators/bitmap/unary/impl/Median.java) that's where my implementation of **medianFilter** can be found.

*width* and *height* variables are for the size of *dest* and are available as class member variables. The pixels are linearized into a one dimensional array.

```
private void medianFilterSquare(int[] source, int[] dest, int rWidth,
        int rHeight, int radius) {
    // Source has been reflected into a border of size radius
    // This makes it radius * 2 pixels wider and taller than the dest
    int r,g,b;
    int destOffset, rOffset, kOffset;

    // The first offset into the source to calculate a median for
    // This corresponds to the first pixel in dest
    int rFirst = radius + (rWidth*radius);

    // We use a square kernel with the radius passed
    int neighbours = (radius+radius+1)*(radius+radius+1);

    int index;

    // Arrays to accumulate the values for median calculation
    int[] rs = new int[neighbours];
    int[] gs = new int[neighbours];
    int[] bs = new int[neighbours];

    // Declaring outside the loop helps speed? I'm sure this is done for me
    // by the compiler
    int pixel;

    // Iterate over the destination pixels
    for(int x = 0; x < height; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < width; y++){
            // Offset into destination
            destOffset = x + (y * width);
            // Offset into source with border size radius
            rOffset = destOffset + rFirst + (y * (radius *2));

            index = 0;

            // Iterate over kernel
            for(int xk = -radius; xk < radius ; xk ++){
                for(int yk = -radius; yk < radius ; yk ++){
                    kOffset = rOffset + (xk + (rWidth*yk));
                    pixel = source[kOffset];
                    // Color.red is equivalent to (pixel>>16) & 0xFF
                    rs[index] = Color.red(pixel);
                    gs[index] = Color.green(pixel);
                    bs[index] = Color.blue(pixel);
                    index++;
                }   
            }
            r = medianFilter(rs);
            g = medianFilter(gs);
            b = medianFilter(bs);

            dest[destOffset] = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
        }           
    }       
}
```

Comment: The bit shift and logical operations should be relatively fast.  Are you sure it's not the code in between those two lines that is the bottleneck?

Comment: How do you "find median for the kernel." Can we see code?

Comment: In fact, you're not even showing us how you get g, b, or a. Why not post all the code?

Comment: Certainly, I was trying to save you from my headache, any help greatly appreciated, I'm in a bit of a bind trying to get this to run in a reasonable time! Code to follow

Comment: Thanks for the code. Your real problem is that you're doing the same operations on the same pixels over and over. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, it's possible that it's the bit in between which is causing the problem. One thing I would say (which may be obvious, but anyway) - don't just profile the application on a desktop VM and assume that the bottleneck will be in the same place. I wouldn't be at all surprised to find entirely different bottlenecks within Dalvik.

Is it possible for you to work with the values still shifted? For instance, if you were to *just* mask for different colours:

```
int r = pixel & 0xff0000;
int g = pixel & 0xff00;
int b = pixel & 0xff;
```

could you tweak your processing algorithm accordingly?

One final thought: I always find the precedence of shift operators confusing. I'd *strongly* recommend that from a readability point of view, you bracket them:

```
r = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
pixel = a | (r <<16) | (g << 8) | b;
```

Irrelevant to performance, but if I were a maintainer I'd certainly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

The fastet way to get your r,g,b values should be

```
new byte[] {
  (byte)(value >>> 24),
  (byte)(value >>> 16),
  (byte)(value >>> 8),
  (byte)value
};
```

Comment: Whether that's fastest depends on all kinds of things, including whether the processor has a barrel shifter or not. What processor is this for? x86 or ARM or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Concentrating on how to do the bit operations is a distraction. It only matters how you're doing these operations because you're needlessly processing the same pixel over and over.

You're calling median filter for every pixel three times, and you're getting multiple pixels around the pixel *per pixel*. Which means you're doing all that bit work for the same pixel multiple times. You have `for` loops nested four deep!

If your radius is 5, you're processing 121 pixels. Then you move down by one and process 121 pixels again, and you've already converted all but 11 of them! You do the same thing for every pixel down, then move to the right one pixel. For a radius of five, you're doing two orders of magnitude as many rgb conversions as you have to.

I'd suggest keeping your image in or converting your image to separate red, blue, and green arrays *first*.

---

If radius is large, you could keep the red, blue, and green sums as you move along, subtracting out the pixels from the top and adding in the pixels from the bottom as you crawl down the bitmap, but that would make the code a touch more complicated. Whether you add code to optimize further depends on your requirements.

---

Also, you have a bunch of little things that could be optimized. I'm not sure if the compiler is taking care of them or not. For instance, you could do some strength reduction. You don't need any of the multiplications you have in the lines that calculate `neighbors`, `destOffset`, `rOffset`, or `kOffset`. Addition is all you need for those if you refactor the code a bit.

Comment: poor naming on my part, medianFilter should just be called median, it finds the median of an array of integers.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. it's the fact that you're doing the same processing to the same pixels over and over. Although there's a lot more room for improvement, separating the whole image out to red, green, and blue parts is the biggest fish here.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but I need to find the median of the reds, greens and blues in the image for the kernel of pixels around each pixel. I don't see how I could call median less, it needs to be called 3 times for each pixel. Unless I'm missing something obvious which I sincerely hope I am.

Comment: You still need to call it for red, green, and blue. But you don't need to call those for every neighbor for every pixel. Imagine you're at your house and you're counting roof tiles on the closest 5 neighbors' houses. Then you walk over to your next door neighbor's house and count all the roof tiles for his 5 closest neighbors. See how much work you're repeating? So first break the image into red, green, and blue pieces. Then do the algorithm on those pieces. You still have to average the neighborhood, but you don't need to do all that extra processing per pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You can occasionally get away with doing arithmetic on the red & blue components simultaneously in a single int:

```
int average(int rgb1, int rgb2)
{
    int rb = (((rgb1 & 0xFF00FF) + (rgb2 & 0xFF00FF)) >> 1) & 0xFF00FF;
    int g = (((rgb1 & 0xFF00) + (rgb2 & 0xFF00)) >> 1) & 0xFF00;
    return (rb | g);
}
```

because the red and blue components are separated by 8 bits, they don't interfere with each other.

I've never seen a significant (more than 5-10%) speedup from this though.

Comment: Even with 8 bits of separation, he could begin to run into trouble if his radius exceeds 7. With a radius of 8, he'd have 289 neighbors to average.